# MYSQL - SQL como hacer una suma de varios totales

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench, mysqlconnector, mysqldb

tengo esta consulta que me devuelve un total de registros agrupando por idioma.
Como veis tengo 10+20+5 (lo que daria un total de los totales de 35)

Pues la consulta es esta, y no se me ocurre como hacer que bien en una COLUMNA mas o en una ROW debajo me de dicho valor.

```
Select count(*) as total,lang from registros_coches
group by lang
order by empresa asc
```

Valores que obtengo de la query

10   es
20   en
5    it

Comment: ¿Has probado con un case  when then? Un saludo

Comment: Tampoco sirve porque el resultado anterior devuelve 3 registros y lo haría por cada uno.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes utilizar el modificador del GROUP BY WITH ROLLUP https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-modifiers.html

```
SELECT 
  registro_coches.lang, 
  sum(registro_coches.values) as total
FROM registro_coches
GROUP BY registro_coches.lang WITH ROLLUP
```

El ejemplo en: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/0b52f4/1

Comment: Gracias, si ejecuto esta consulta me devuelve un único registro que son 35.

Comment: Lo que intento hacer es que devuelta las 3 filas agrupadas con los totales de 10,20 y 5. Y luego ya sea en una columna más o otro row el valor 35 (total de totales). Gracias

Comment: Puedes añadir al GROUP BY WITH ROLLUP https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-modifiers.html, modifico la respuesta.